# Change y_axis to begin 0 on top

Tags: matplotlib

By default, when I add axes to an image in matplotlib, the x axis begins at 0 and increases from left to right and the y-axis begins at 0, increasing from bottom to top.  I would like to have the y-axis beginning at zero, but from top to bottom (that is, 0 on the top, and the maximum value on the bottom) How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to reverse the y-axis. This can be done with

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

which takes the current axis `plt.gca()` and calls its method [`invert_yaxis()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/axes_api.html?#matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis) to invert the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply call plt.ylim() and put the coordinates in reverse order. I know I always fine-tune the range of all plots by hand anyway, so this is easier in that situation. So let's say you have a plot that runs from 0 to 10, you would just call

```
plt.ylim(10,0)
```

and it will flip the y-axis.